# Configure CentOS kiosk mode and restrict to single application

Tags: firefox, opera, centos7, kiosk, kiosk-mode

We have created a xguest login on CentOS. We need only browser to be used in xguest login and not any other application. How to get this one done?

We tried the following command

```
~]# setsebool -P allow_xguest_exec_content off
```

the home screen appears blank for the above command. We want only the browser to be accessed by the xguest user. How to activate the browser for xguest?

Answer (score 0):

Try this my script: https://github.com/VoidVolker/kiosk - for CentOS it need some changes, I think, not tested in CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's going to work but u can fine some useful information bellow:

https://gist.github.com/voor/8215016d722da5df0caf629469fe7e80

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/lockdown-single-app-mode.html.en

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/single-application-ode

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/user-sessions

Hope it is helpful.